# Regularization for softmax in gradient descent

Tags: python, classification, softmax

I'm writing a gradient descent function for a multi-class classifier using softmax. I'm a bit confused about how regularization should work in the gradient function. I've specified my matrix, X, such that the first column is populated by ones, and w is a matrix where each row corresponds to the weights of features and each column corresponds to a label. I understand that the bias term/intercept should not be regularized. However, I'm not clear on how to leave the bias term out.

Some of the code I'm learning from has the following in the function to calculate the gradient:

```
scores = np.dot(X,w)
predictions = softmax_function(scores)

gradient = -np.dot(X.T,y_actual-y_predictions)/len(y_actual)
regularizer = np.hstack((np.zeros((w.shape[0],1)),w[:,1:w.shape[1]]))
return (gradient, regularizer)
```

Then, when w is updated at the end of the epoch:

`w_new = w_old - learning_rate*(gradient+regularizer*lambd)`

So, here's my question. In the code above, why is hstack() used to populate the first column in the regularization term with zeros? It seems like we'd want to use vstack() to make the first row in the regularizer zeros, since the bias weights are going to be the first row.

Comment: np.dot(X,w) means you're dealing with columns of w

Comment: Right, rows of X are multiplied with columns of w, which are the weights for each label. This should mean we want to zero out the first row of w (weights for the first term), not the first column (weights for the first label), correct?